# Spark delete/remove partitions older than retention period from parquet

Tags: azure, dataframe, scala, apache-spark

The data is being written into an ADLS Gen2 location partitioned by Date in parquet format

```
deltaDFFinal.write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .format("parquet")
      .partitionBy("Date")
      .save(ADLSGen2Path)
```

The data is written into folders with the partition names as below

Date=2022-02-09

Date=2022-02-10

..

I would like to delete the partitions which are older than 7days and want to keep Append as the logic due to high volumes of data instead of overwrite

Answer (score 0):

Deleting expired partitions while keeping the `append` mode of writing may not be directly possible.
This is a data lifecycle related issue, and the recommended practice is to periodically perform cleanup jobs like `alter table ... drop partition ...`

Comment: Could you please give more info/skeleton code on what and how can we achieve this using alter table....drop partition...

Comment: Schedule lifecycle management jobs on a daily basis. The logic is to push forward 7 days from the current date to obtain the date corresponding to the latest partition to be deleted, such as ```2022-02-09```. Use the ``alter table table_name drop partition (Date<='2022-02-09')`` statement to delete all expired partitions.

Answer (score 0):

spark.sql("delete from delta.`<delta path>` where date< previous date")